# DirectX 11 diffuse lighting issue

Tags: 3d, directx, game-engine, directx-11

currently i am learning DirectX 11 from these tutorials:
http://www.rastertek.com/tutdx11.html

The tutorials worked fine and so i implemented the things in my little engine. The problem is that directx doesnt render the diffuse light on all polygons and the direction of the light seems to be wrong.

Here is a picture of a rendered plane with two polygons:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9m94n1q7oichi2b/DX11Plane.PNG

Here are some parts of the source code:

```
//The vertex structure
struct BE_SVERTEX{
    BE_SVERTEX(){

    }

    BE_SVERTEX(D3DXVECTOR3 position, D3DXVECTOR2 texture, D3DXVECTOR3 normal){
        this->position = position;
        this->texture = texture;
        this->normal = normal;
    }

    BE_SVERTEX(const BE_SVERTEX &v){
        this->normal = v.normal;
        this->position = v.position;
        this->texture = v.texture;
    }

    D3DXVECTOR3 position;
    D3DXVECTOR2 texture;
    D3DXVECTOR3 normal;
};
```

Here i am creating the vertex and index buffer:

```
        aVertices = new BE_SVERTEX[vVertices.size()];
        aIndices = new unsigned long[vIndices.size()];

        //Filling the vertex and index array with the data from the wavefront file
        for (int i = 0; i < vVertices.size(); i++){
            //To test the normalvector of the plane i have set the normalvectors from all vertices of the plane manually
            aVertices[i].normal = D3DXVECTOR3{ 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f};
            aVertices[i].position = vVertices[i].position;
            aVertices[i].texture = vVertices[i].texture;
            //The indices for the index buffer. Currently the index buffer is unnecessary because the engine creates for each polygon 3 new vertices.
            aIndices[i] = vIndices[i];
        }

        //Creating the vertex buffer
        vertexBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
        vertexBufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(BE_SVERTEX) * vVertices.size();
        vertexBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
        vertexBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
        vertexBufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
        vertexBufferDesc.StructureByteStride = 0;

        vertexData.pSysMem = aVertices;
        vertexData.SysMemPitch = 0;
        vertexData.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;

        mesh->vertexBuffer = NULL;

        result = device->CreateBuffer(&vertexBufferDesc, &vertexData, &mesh->vertexBuffer);
        if (FAILED(result)){
            return BE_SRESULT{ 7, false };
        }
        else{
            //Creating the index buffer
            indexBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
            indexBufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(unsigned long) * vIndices.size();
            indexBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
            indexBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
            indexBufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
            indexBufferDesc.StructureByteStride = 0;

            indexData.pSysMem = aIndices;
            indexData.SysMemPitch = 0;
            indexData.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;

            mesh->indexBuffer = NULL;

            result = device->CreateBuffer(&indexBufferDesc, &indexData, &mesh-       >indexBuffer);
            if (FAILED(result)){
                return BE_SRESULT{ 7, false };
            }
```

Some parts of the creation of the shader:

```
        //Creating the input layout
        polygonLayout[0].SemanticName = "POSITION";
        polygonLayout[0].SemanticIndex = 0;
        polygonLayout[0].Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT;
        polygonLayout[0].InputSlot = 0;
        polygonLayout[0].AlignedByteOffset = 0;
        polygonLayout[0].InputSlotClass = D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA;
        polygonLayout[0].InstanceDataStepRate = 0;

        polygonLayout[1].SemanticName = "TEXCOORD";
        polygonLayout[1].SemanticIndex = 0;
        polygonLayout[1].Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT;
        polygonLayout[1].InputSlot = 0;
        polygonLayout[1].AlignedByteOffset = D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT;
        polygonLayout[1].InputSlotClass = D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA;
        polygonLayout[1].InstanceDataStepRate = 0;

        polygonLayout[2].SemanticName = "NORMAL";
        polygonLayout[2].SemanticIndex = 0;
        polygonLayout[2].Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT;
        polygonLayout[2].InputSlot = 0;
        polygonLayout[2].AlignedByteOffset = D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT;
        polygonLayout[2].InputSlotClass = D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA;
        polygonLayout[2].InstanceDataStepRate = 0;

        numElements = sizeof(polygonLayout) / sizeof(polygonLayout[0]);

        result = device->CreateInputLayout(polygonLayout, numElements, vertexShaderBuffer->GetBufferPointer(), vertexShaderBuffer->GetBufferSize(), &layout);
```

The rendering function of the shader:

```
//Setting rendering settings. This methode is called every frame before shader   rendering.
BE_SRESULT ObjectElements::BE_OE_Shader::setShaderParameters(D3DXMATRIX worldMatrix, D3DXMATRIX viewMatrix, D3DXMATRIX projectionMatrix, ID3D11ShaderResourceView *texture,   D3DXVECTOR3 lightDirection, D3DXVECTOR4 diffuseColor){
    HRESULT result;
    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mappedResource;
    unsigned int bufferNumber;
    MatrixBufferType *dataPtr;
    LightBufferType *dataPtr2;

    D3DXMatrixTranspose(&worldMatrix, &worldMatrix);
    D3DXMatrixTranspose(&viewMatrix, &viewMatrix);
    D3DXMatrixTranspose(&projectionMatrix, &projectionMatrix);

    result = immediateDevice->Map(matrixBuffer, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &mappedResource);
    if (FAILED(result)){
        return BE_SRESULT{ 8, false };
    }
    else{

        dataPtr = (MatrixBufferType*)mappedResource.pData;

        dataPtr->world = worldMatrix;
        dataPtr->view = viewMatrix;
        dataPtr->projection = projectionMatrix;

        immediateDevice->Unmap(matrixBuffer, 0);

        bufferNumber = 0;

        immediateDevice->VSSetConstantBuffers(bufferNumber, 1, &matrixBuffer);
        immediateDevice->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &texture);

        result = immediateDevice->Map(lightBuffer, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &mappedResource);

        if (FAILED(result)){
            return BE_SRESULT{ 8, false };
        }
        else{

            dataPtr2 = (LightBufferType*)mappedResource.pData;

            dataPtr2->diffuseColor = diffuseColor;
            dataPtr2->lightDirection = lightDirection;
            dataPtr2->padding = 0.0f;

            immediateDevice->Unmap(lightBuffer, 0);

            bufferNumber = 0;

            immediateDevice->PSSetConstantBuffers(bufferNumber, 1, &lightBuffer);

            return BE_SRESULT{ 0, true };
        }
    }
}

   //The render function of the shader
   void ObjectElements::BE_OE_Shader::render(int indexCount){
       immediateDevice->IASetInputLayout(layout);

       immediateDevice->VSSetShader(vertexShader, NULL, 0);
       immediateDevice->PSSetShader(pixelShader, NULL, 0);

       immediateDevice->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &sampleState);

       immediateDevice->DrawIndexed(indexCount, 0, 0);
   }
```

The light direction is D3DXVECTOR3{0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}.

I have searched already for hours to find the failure but the light still doesnt work correctly. The shader i use are the same as the shader from the tutorial.

I hope somebody can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vertex buffer contains a float2 uv according to `BE_SVERTEX`, but the input layout declare a float3, and since you use automatic offsets, the normal is wrongly offset-ed.

This

```
polygonLayout[1].Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT;
```

Become

```
polygonLayout[1].Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT;
```